# What's the best approach to showcase benefits from SQL - NoSQL environment?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, redis, nosql

I was asked to create a little environment showcasing benefits from using NoSQL - SQL hybrid over only SQL database. Since my background is mostly Admin/DevOps I have basic knowledge about databases, but I've never done something like this.

I thought of creating a VM hosting MySQL or PostgreSQL instance and populating it with Sakila or other free database as starting point and the second VM with Mongo/Redis, but I don't know what to do from this point.
How can I integrate those databases? How can I run tests and what should I test - query response times? Is this even good strategy?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is info about [MongoDB and MySQL compared](https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Try to make two data models for the twitter data feed, one in relational SQL tables and another one in a single JSON document.

Used MySQL as a relational DB AND MongoDB as NoSQL DB.

The main performance indicator will show up when you start executing SQL on table joins in MySQL against executing MongoDB queries where there is no need to joins.

This is an idea but there are many other advantages.